# How to verify in bash if a certificate is already imported in the KeyChain?

Tags: security, bash, keychain, ssl

I want to check, from the command line, if a certificate is already imported in the KeyChain in order to avoid doing a `sudo security add-trusted-cert ...` if that's not necessarily.

I already have the certificate on disk but I don't know how it verify if it already installed in the KeyChain or not.

Comment: There is a `find-certificate` option, does this help?

Comment: I looked at it it it does not seem of much help because it can only search by `name` or `email address`, and not even the full CN name. This means that extracting the name using something linke ` openssl x509 -noout -subject -in Eng-CA.crt | sed -e 's/^subject.*CN=\([^/]*\).*$/\1/'` would give you name that is not unique enough for a search, I get something like "Engineering Services". I can also extract the hash from both the PEM certificate or to tell find-certificates to return it but I cannot search by it.

Comment: Perhaps you could `grep` the output of `security export -k yourKeychain -t certs`. Also see https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/20059/verify-the-existence-of-a-system-keychain-certificate.